# Porting OpenGL Programs from C to WebGL and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, websocket, webgl

I'm trying to port a very complex 3D modeling program(written in C) to webGL. The program has it's own physics engine written from scratch, and I would like to use the transform data which is output by the physics engine as matrices to transform objects rendered in a webPage.

The program is so massive that I would like to keep the physics engine in C as is, but take the graphics part into the browser.

My crazy idea is to have the physics engine running constantly on the server, and then stream the transformation matrices to the client and apply the transformations to pre-rendered WebGL objects.

Is this possible to do?

**Clarification:** The program is a viewer, so all of the physics backend is isolated from user input. The user will, however, be able to manipulate camera angles on the client side.

**Update:** I've decided on implementing the following solution, let me know if any of this is wrong: I will host the C program as a daemon using node.js, and pump data using websockets to the front end - which is pixi.js(for 2D elements) and babylon.js(or three.js)(for 3D elements). The data will be comprised of JSON objects(quaternions or sine/cosine matricies) that will be handled on the front end in javascript and applied once per second(fps doesn't matter in my situation, so it's okay)

Comment: have you considered [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki)?

Comment: I have already attempted using emscripten, but my project is simply too large/complex (its about 12 source files, an equitable number of header files, all of which are between 2000-6000 lines of code) to work well with it. Also the project uses functions available only in OpenGL 3.0 and later, so emscripten doesn't have a mature emulator to deal with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented this successfully by doing the following:

Within my C code I used the hiredis library to publish a JSON formatted string to redis, hosted on an ec2 machine with nginx. Next I used primus(a node_module) to set up a subscriber websocket from redis to a node.js app server. Node then serves the data(whenever there's a publish) to the client, where I parsed out the JSON and used the object to draw my scene.

This solution is really quick and easy, and is a very effective means of pushing large amounts of data(in the form of a JSON object) through to many clients. It also allows for setting up multiple channels within C(for different datasets), at which point you can pick and choose which channels you want to listen to on the client side(or listen to all of them at once!). I'm away from my computer with the code, but I can post more detailed instructions/code examples on how to do this at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Push and pop matrix are auxiliary (not a core part of the rendering pipeline) so you can replicate them with a custom stack.

About the whole crazy idea:
In case of interactive physics, latency can be a problem and you will need some sort of position extrapolation on the client side. Worst case is if you have multiply clients. Imagine that one client caused some physics event then it will send data to the server and server will send it to the another client. So you will have effectively double latency and at the end it will be really hard to resolve inconsistency when you have 3 states (or even more if you have more clients) one unique state at each client and one actual state at server. The bigger the latency - the higher inconsistency. And physics is really sensitive to this kind of inconsistency, because it tends to snowball. So your clients likely to see some weird popping in and out of existence, teleportations, falling through solid objects.

Comment: The only interaction that the clients will be allowed is moving the cameras, which will be another transformation matrix on the client side. The physics engine and the data it produces will be protected from the user (it creates the transform matrices using live streamed telemetry data, not user interaction). Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the post to be more descriptive. Thanks for your answer on top though :).

Comment: @Boogiechillin So basically your front-end doesn't have to know what is the transformation  source.  It can be prerecorded static data, some animation or physics engine. You will simply feed transformation to some WebGL rendered like three.js So If you learn how to use it and  how to setup WebSockets then it  will be trivial task. I'm afraid there is no easy way :)

Comment: Yeah that's another route that I've considered. Thanks for your help! I'll post updates on what I found worked best.